# Angular paste in dfferent targets

Tags: angular

I want to paste data in 2 different targets.

```
<div class="row">
<div
    class="c1 box"
    (paste)="log($event, 'c1')"
></div>
<div
    class="c2 box"
    (paste)="log($event, 'c2')"
></div>
```

This way when pasting something the event should have the target as the element where cursor is currently right? 
No, it's targeting always the first element which I am listening the event, ignoring the second element when I have the cursor on it and paste something.

I'd appreciate some help from you.

here's the repro:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oaxxrm

Comment: your stackblitz works if you click c2 and then paste - same for c1 - i guess its because c2 is given the focus when it is clicked, you may need to put some code in to give c1 or c2 the focus on hover - tested with Chrome

Comment: Yes, you are right, and I found out the problem was on a method where I was passing the wrong index to add the data.